# mvc5 identity 2.0.0 email confirmation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, confirmation

I'm using MVC5, identity 2.0.0. There is email registration with email confirmation. It is possible to get or set confirmation validity?
I think, it is wrong when people has registred by his email address and he can confirm it after one year, or he never confirm this address, because email belongs to other people.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is probably not the answer you want, but based on some research it looks like this is an area that still needs some development in ASP.NET Identity.

[This guy](http://brockallen.com/2013/10/20/the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-of-asp-net-identity/) basically says that .NET Identity has got a long way to go, and lists email verification as a weak point of the library, but that was before 2.0.0 came out.

The [Windows Azure website has an example](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-deploy-aspnet-mvc-app-membership-oauth-sql-database/) application using Identity, but it doesn't seem to have email verification built in.

[This guy has an example](http://www.codenutz.com/verify-email-address-entity-framework-code-first-migrations/) that is closer to what you want with email verification. But it would take some additional enhancements to get to where you want to be. And I'm not sure if he is using Identity 2. You might would want to add a date stamp, and disallow verifications that come in after a certain window of time.

Lastly, the [Microsoft ASP.NET website has a request in for a full example](http://aspnet.uservoice.com/forums/228522-show-me-how-with-code/suggestions/5672298-asp-net-2-identity-walkthrough-registration-emai) of using email verification with Identity 2.0. But as of now, it is still under review.

**edit June 5, 2014**

To follow up on this question, it looks like the ASP.Net team has put together a couple of walkthroughs for setting up email account verification with Identity. Check out the links

here (http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/account-confirmation-and-password-recovery-with-aspnet-identity)

and here (http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/two-factor-authentication-using-sms-and-email-with-aspnet-identity).